# Display array of objects not working in browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am wanting to create an array of objects and display a specific list of properties when certain conditions are met.

The following code does what I want when I print it to the console or use `document.write`.

```
var people = [{ 
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 23,
    },{ 
    firstName: 'Jane',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 53,
    }]

    for(i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        if(people[i].age < 65){
            document.write(people[i].firstName + ' ' + 
            people[i].lastName + ' has printed to document. <br>');             
        }
    }
```

But when I go to run the code in the browser, using `document.getElementById`, only the last item is displaying.

```
for(i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    if(people[i].age < 65){
        result = 'Only ' + people[i].firstName + ' ' + 
            people[i].lastName + ' is printed to document. Why?';               
    }
}
document.getElementById('names').innerHTML = result;
```

Could someone explain to  me why all items appear using `document.write`?
While only the last item appears when using `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in this line:

```
result = 'Only ' + people[i].firstName + ' ' + 
        people[i].lastName + ' is printed to document. Why?';
```

Because you're assigning the message string to `result` variable. Since you are in a `loop`, the `result` variable will just hold the last value.

You have to `concat` the message to `result` variable.

```
for(i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
    if(people[i].age < 65){
        result += 'Only ' + people[i].firstName + ' ' + 
            people[i].lastName + ' is printed to document. Why?';               
    }
}
```

Also, you can use `string templates` for formatting the message.

```
result += `Only ${people[i].firstName} ${people[i].lastName} is printed to document. Why?`;
```